# Return to same page state in ASP Web Pages (WebGrid)

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, webgrid

I have created a page in ASP Web Pages with WebMatrix, where I use a WebGrid with paging to show the data from a query. I also have a search form on the top to search though the database. The rows are clickable, and when clicked it goes to a details page for that row, but when I go back, the WebGrid is reset. Is there any way to save the state of the webgrid, and eventually the filled search forms if they have been used, when I go back? It seems to me that when I just go back, without refresh, the page doesn't query the database again, because it is faster than refreshing. But the WebGrid is reset anyway to the first gridpage.
Can someone help?
I also noticed that WebGrid to go to its other pages. Does it retrieve all rows in the beginning or everytime in paging?